# How to get a list of random numbers between two numbers with a specified mean and standard deviation (in Python)?

Tags: python, list, random, mean, standard-deviation

I have two outer limits, a mean and a standard deviation value. I need to generate a specified number of random decimal numbers within the two limits included having the specified mean and standard deviation value. I have written two code blocks which I have found on the Internet. But crosschecking by finding the mean of the list, I found that the mean obtained was different. How to get the correct mean and standard deviation value?

One piece of code is:

```
import scipy.stats as stats

a, b = 27.6, 59.4
mu, sigma = 32, 54
dist = stats.truncnorm((a - mu) / sigma, (b - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)

agesp = dist.rvs(419)
```

The other piece of code is:

```
values = []
while len(values) < 419:
    sample = random.gauss(32, 54)
    if sample >= 27.6 and sample < 59.4:
        values.append(sample)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the first piece of code.  In the second piece of code, you are just generating a gaussian distribution with mean 32 and stddev 54, and then truncating everything that falls outside of the range you want.   You  are not chopping symmetrically around the mean, so the resulting distribution will not have the same mean.  I'm pretty sure it'll also have a smaller stddev simply by virtue that the outliers are being eliminated.

Comment: the mean and standard deviation of a [truncated normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) is more complicated than just the `mu` and `sigma` you pass, see the wikipedia page for details.  your problem also seems ill defined, the maximum SD you can get from that `a` and `b` is ~9.2